# Group sum on 2 variables and subtraction from total

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` of the following form:-

```
library(data.table)
b <- data.table(Code_Nm = c(rep("a", 3), rep("b", 3), rep("d", 3)),
            Year = rep(2011:2013, 3), total = rep(10, 9),
            a = c(rep(0, 3), 1:6), b = c(7:9, 0, 0, 0, 10:12), d = c(13:18, 0, 0, 0))
b

#   Code_Nm Year total a  b  d
#1:       a 2011    10 0  7 13
#2:       a 2012    10 0  8 14
#3:       a 2013    10 0  9 15
#4:       b 2011    10 1  0 16
#5:       b 2012    10 2  0 17
#6:       b 2013    10 3  0 18
#7:       d 2011    10 4 10  0
#8:       d 2012    10 5 11  0
#9:       d 2013    10 6 12  0
```

I want to get a `data.table` such that the last column named `actual` has the value equal to the `total` minus the sum of yearly groups of each `Code_Nm`. I.e. for `a` in `2011` it is `10` minus sum of all the `2011` values but from column `a`. This is equal to `10 - (1+4)`.

Similarly for `a` in `2012`, it is `10` minus sum of all `2012` values but from column `a`. This is equal to `10 - (2+5)`.

Similary for `b` in `2011` it is `10` minus sum of all the `2011` values but from column `b`. This is equal to `10 - (7+10)`. For `b` in `2012`, it is `10` minus sum of all `2012` values but from column `b`. This is equal to `10 - (8+11)`.

And similary for `d` column as well.

The final result is the following `data.table`:-

```
b <- data.table(Code_Nm = c(rep("a", 3), rep("b", 3), rep("d", 3)),
            Year = rep(2011:2013, 3), total = rep(10, 9),
            a = c(rep(0, 3), 1:6), b = c(7:9, 0, 0, 0, 10:12), d = c(13:18, 0, 0, 0),
            actual = c(5, 3, 1, -7, -9, -11, -19, -21, -23))
b

#   Code_Nm Year total a  b  d actual
#1:       a 2011    10 0  7 13      5
#2:       a 2012    10 0  8 14      3
#3:       a 2013    10 0  9 15      1
#4:       b 2011    10 1  0 16     -7
#5:       b 2012    10 2  0 17     -9
#6:       b 2013    10 3  0 18    -11
#7:       d 2011    10 4 10  0    -19
#8:       d 2012    10 5 11  0    -21
#9:       d 2013    10 6 12  0    -23
```

Please give a solution using a `data.table`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the code below

```
b[, actual := total - colSums(cbind(a, b, d)[, .SD[, Code_Nm]]), Year][]
```

which gives

```
   Code_Nm Year total a  b  d actual
1:       a 2011    10 0  7 13      5
2:       a 2012    10 0  8 14      3
3:       a 2013    10 0  9 15      1
4:       b 2011    10 1  0 16     -7
5:       b 2012    10 2  0 17     -9
6:       b 2013    10 3  0 18    -11
7:       d 2011    10 4 10  0    -19
8:       d 2012    10 5 11  0    -21
9:       d 2013    10 6 12  0    -23
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `rowSums` on the Subset of data.table (`.SD`) after specifying `.SDcols` with the columns of interest and subtract from 'total'

```
b[, actual := total  - rowSums(.SD), .SDcols = a:d]
```

-output

```
b
#    Code_Nm Year total a b d actual
#1:       a 2011    10 0 2 3      5
#2:       a 2012    10 0 3 4      3
#3:       a 2013    10 0 4 5      1
#4:       b 2011    10 1 0 6      3
#5:       b 2012    10 2 0 7      1
#6:       b 2013    10 3 0 8     -1
#7:       d 2011    10 4 5 0      1
#8:       d 2012    10 5 6 0     -1
#9:       d 2013    10 6 7 0     -3
```

Comment: Well, the answer is right. But in the solution, what is actually happening is `10-(2+3)` for the first row and so on. This gives the correct answer for the first row because `2+3` is essentially equal to `1+4`. Let me change the example in my question, and then, perhaps you'll understand.

Comment: I have edited the question, can you please try now?

Answer (score 1):

### Updated:

The idea is I can transpose each group for columns `a,b,d`, then I can still use the previous method `total - rowSum(.SD)`.

```
cols1 <- names(b)[4:6]
cols2 <- paste(names(b)[4:6],2,sep = "")

b[,(cols2):= lapply(split.default(as.data.frame(t(.SD)),cols1),unlist),
  by = Year,
  .SDcols = cols1]

b[, actual := total - rowSums(.SD), .SDcols = cols2]
b[,(cols2):=NULL][]
```

### Previous

Is this your desired result?

```
b[,actual := total - ( a + b + d)][]
```

or

```
b[, actual := total - apply(.SD,1,sum),.SDcols = c(4:6)][]
```

Comment: The answer is right, but can you refer to the 1st comment I've written on the first answer. And then try.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option using `melt` and then update by reference using a join:

```
m <- melt(b, id.vars="Year", measure.vars=c("a","b","d"))[, sum(value), .(Year, Code_Nm=variable)]
b[, actual := m[.SD, on=.(Code_Nm, Year), i.total - x.V1]]
```